# How to Draw a Rectangle to select multiple items using Angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Hello I want to know how can I draw a Rectangle to select multiple items using Angular 2+.

I have this working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0DAFaBQiMez8uhxPZQgB?p=preview) corde where I want to select the items drawing a rectangle like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JancoBH/weLrw4ze/2/)

Someone tried to helped me but it didn't work, here is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JtkBSRhPNxAphLOtYFWa?p=preview) :(

```
export class CheckPlunker {}
```

I'm noob with Angular 2 component and I need help. thanks for read =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jzJvJdtHB5rz3CTo5xb2?p=preview) is the solution of the 90% of my problem, now I need to do something more similar to this [demo](http://maxazan.github.io/angular-multiple-selection/)

```
export class CheckPlunker {}
```